# Calculating the probability of tournament results of a skill based game?

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations

If we have a pool of players who's skill levelss are normally distributed, and we sample some number of players from that pool (not necessarily independently of their skill) for a "Tournament", how can we calculate the probability of a given set of standings for that tournament?

I.E. we have the final standings: Player A in first, Player B in second...Player Z in 26th.

The structure of the tournament uses 5 rounds of Swiss Pairings, such that the players are randomly pitted against each other in the first round, but after that everyone on 1 win will face each other, and then in the next round everyone on 2 wins, etc. And we assume that the more skilled player will win in an individual game.

How can we work out the probability of a given table of results?

This is part of a larger problem of trying to collate multiple tournament results of different subsets of players, and trying to combine those into a single ranking system.

Thanks!

EDIT: The pairing system will match players randomly if they are on the same number of wins in each round, if it is not possible to match everyone on the same number of wins then a player will be randomly picked who is as close to that number of wins as possible.

Comment: So the randomness is in the pairings but not the individual games?  Should we assume there are a multiple of $32$ players ($26$ will not guarantee that your equal wins in each round condition can be satisfied)? What counts as a different table of results - perhaps the number of wins for each player?

Comment: Since the skill levels of the players are distributed according to a continuous distribution, the probability that two players have the same skill level is zero. Since the more skilled player always wins, the actual skill levels are irrelevant and the results are completely determined by the ranking of the players sampled. Thus, the assumption of players being sampled from a normal distribution is irrelevant; you could more simply introduce the problem as $n$ players that can be ranked by skill level.

Comment: As to the remaining problem of finding the probability of a given table of results, you'll need to specify the precise pairing algorithm. Different pairing algorithms are in use for Swiss tournaments, and the result may depend on the algorithm.

Comment: edited the op! thanks

Comment: With your edit, which complicates the question, simulation may provide a good approximation of say the different possible positions of the 5th ranked player.  It will also force you to implement your Swiss system (which typically prevent pairs meeting more than once) and so avoid more detailed theoretical questions